# A Prolog rule that returns the subgoals in a proof search

Tags: prolog

I am looking for a simple/straightforward way to write a rule that outputs the antecedents in a proof search (successes of subgoals). Suppose i have the code

```
winsLottery(john).
healthy(john).
rich(X):-winsLottery(X).
happy(X):-rich(X), healthy(X).
```

I would like a rule `antecedents(L, happy(john))`, which returns

```
L = [
[rich(john), healthy(john)],
[winsLottery(john), healthy(john)]
]
```

I know about `trace/0` but i am looking for a rule. I also tried `clause/2` but this just gets the clause where the target event occurs and not any previous antecedents.

My motive is that I am interested in constructing a system that provides explanations for events. I know that i could do `causes([rich(X), healthy(X)], happy(X))` in the knowledge base, but i am looking for clean and simple Prolog code that i can translate to classic first order logic (where lists are a bit problematic).

Thanks!

Comment: Why use `event/1` and not use the goals directly?

Comment: @repeat Event is not important here; its just a remainder from my real program where predicates fall into different classes.

Comment: @repeat i'll update the code for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Of interest: [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/prolog_misc/acomip.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the suggestions of Guy, here is the solution:

```
main:-explain(happy(john)).

winsLottery(john).
healthy(john).
rich(X):-winsLottery(X).
happy(X):-rich(X), healthy(X).

explain(X):-
    clause(X, B),
    B == true.
explain((X1, X2)):-
    explain(X1),
    explain(X2).
explain(X):-
    X \= true,
    X \= (_, _),
    clause(X, B),
    write('An explanation for '), write(X), write(' is: '), nl, write(B), nl, nl,
    explain(B).
```